# /bin/sh: git: command not found. Meteor package installation

Tags: node.js, git, meteor, meteorite

I am adding "googlemaps" package to new meteor project on MacOS. I have installed node and meteorite properly, But when i run the command: "mrt add googlemaps". It shows following error. Any ideas about it?

```
✓ googlemaps
    tag: https://github.com/drewjw81/meteor-googlemaps.git#v0.0.2
ERROR: 127 Command failed: /bin/sh: git: command not found


STDOUT:  

STDERR: /bin/sh: git: command not found



/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:124
        throw "There was a problem cloning repo: " + self.url +
                                                              ^
There was a problem cloning repo: https://github.com/drewjw81/meteor-googlemaps.git
Please check https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#troubleshooting for potential explanations.
```

however, after installing git it shows following error:

```
Stand back while Meteorite does its thing
✓ googlemaps
    tag: https://github.com/drewjw81/meteor-googlemaps.git#v0.0.2
ERROR: null Command failed:  

STDOUT:  

STDERR:  


/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:124
        throw "There was a problem cloning repo: " + self.url +
                                                              ^
There was a problem cloning repo: https://github.com/drewjw81/meteor-googlemaps.git
Please check https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#troubleshooting for potential explanations.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing [git](http://git-scm.com). Install [Xcode from the app store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12). It comes with git. If you are a [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) user, and want the latest version (which I would consider optional in your case), you can install it with `brew update; brew install git`.

Comment: I have installed git and got new error(shown in update question) :( I'm new to mac and confused with this error.

Comment: @nikhilk I'm guessing your process might have terminated in some half-way state when you ran it before you had git installed. And now it may be having trouble picking up where it left off. Can you try re-creating the project from scratch in a new directory and see if get any further?